# Spark submit issue - ps: command not found

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to connect the spark master from the client machine with the Python script.

I'm encountering an error while running my Spark application from the client side. The error message states: `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/bin/load-spark-env.sh: line 68: ps: command not found`. Could someone help me understand what might be causing this issue?

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/bin/load-spark-env.sh: line 68: ps: command not found
```

Here is the Python script, running as `python test.py`:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("PySpark v1") \
    .master("spark://test-spark-master-0.test-spark-headless.test-spark.svc.cluster.local:7077") \
    .getOrCreate()
data = [("John", 25), ("Anna", 30), ("Mike", 35)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["Name", "Age"])
df.show()
filtered_df = df.filter(df["Age"] > 30)
filtered_df.show()
spark.stop()
```

Comment: Most probably the issue is with your PATH. Check [this](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/very-strange-runtime-error-when-running-a-built-script-in-a-shell/12896) if it helps.

Comment: i added path but still same issue.

Answer (score 0):

i added package "apt-get install procps"